# Cryptomator fails to start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have recently been having problems with getting Cryptomator to start on my machine. I am running the latest 1.2.3 version with Ubuntu 14.04.

```
(gdb) r ./Cryptomator
Starting program: /opt/Cryptomator/Cryptomator ./Cryptomator

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe5c2d2b4 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fffe5c2d2b4 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000246 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffe5c2d160 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffff642f990 in VM_Operation::_names () from 
/opt/Cryptomator/runtime/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fffffffd1c0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffff5f5f5cd in VM_Version::get_processor_features() () from 
/opt/Cryptomator/runtime/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent kernel release has broken Cryptomator.

Boot your previous kernel for now.

https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/issues/523 will probably have more details once it's fixed.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. No wonder it stopped working abruptly. I will keep track of that issue. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

Please edit /opt/Cryptomator/app/Cryptomator.cfg and add -Xss2m to the JVMOptions, so it looks like this:

```
[JVMOptions]
 -Xss2m
 -Xmx512m
 -Dcryptomator.logPath=...
```

This solves the issue with the startup and Cryptomator now works as expected.